# Text information retrieval in NLP

Tags: nlp

I have some problems with information retrieval based on the object description.

I have a dataset like this:

```
object | description |
ball   | ball had a radius of 33|
ruler  | ruler material is steal and the length of then is 3 meters
sceen  | Material:plastic,Manufacturer:apple|
```

The description could be a normal sentence of a *scientific description* but I want to get that information. Did anyone have any idea about how I could do that?

In fact I want some idea for how convert then to a dataset like

```
object  | radius | material| lenght | manufacturer 
ball    |  33    |   \     |  \     |  \
ruler   |  \     |  steal  |   3    |  \
sceen   |  \     | plastic |    \   | apple
```

I want any thing like research paper, blog post and tutorial about this problem

Comment: What are you actually asking for? Your question is not clear -- what output do you want to get from what input?

Comment: I want to convert this dataset on to a dataset with information like |object|description| radius| lenght | material |